# take the letters after a specific letter and put them in one variable

Tags: python

i am writing an ai in python and at one step, the user has to input an Url of an image. for the program, he has to put in the whole url, and the letters after the last / seperatly, because the code first downloads the image, and then searches it in the downloads. but, it is annoying for the user to type in the url **and** the name. can anyone help me?

```
def ImageRecognizer():
  print("########################################")
  print()
  print("Enter Image Url:")
  print()
  imageInput = input("")

  try:
    urllib.request.urlopen(imageInput)
  except: 
    print("Url not accessable. Try another.")
    ImageRecognizer()

  print()
  print("nter full name of image:")
  print()
  imageEnding = input("")

  sunflower_url = imageInput
  sunflower_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file(imageEnding, origin=sunflower_url)

  img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
      sunflower_path, target_size=(img_height, img_width)
  )
  img_array = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
  img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0) # Create a batch

  predictions = model.predict(img_array)
  score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])

  print(
      "This image most likely belongs to {} with a {:.2f} percent confidence."
      .format(class_names[np.argmax(score)], 100 * np.max(score))
  )
  time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like `imageInput.split('/')[-1]`?

Comment: i want that the user inputs the url once and that the script then takes the letters after the last / and puts them into an other variable. but not in a list but in 2 different variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
data = imageInput.split('/')
file = data[-1]
path = "/".join(data[:-1])
```

which would put the image name in the file variable and the path to the file in the path variable.

Comment: use `rsplit` for 1 liner

Answer (score 0):

Split the url given by the user using the '/' as the splitter
this will return a list of strings.
Since you want the element as it is the image name, index it using '[-1]'

```
mystr = 'www.google.com/one/two/coffee'

image_name = mystr.split('/')[-1] # split into elements and take the last one


print(image_name)
```

```
>>> 'coffee'
```

Comment: when i have this it gives me the error https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.805972169.4072/fposter,small,wall_texture,product,750x1000.u3.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Terminator\Desktop\predict.py", line 116, in <module>
    ImageRecognizer()
  File "C:\Users\Terminator\Desktop\predict.py", line 96, in ImageRecognizer
    image_name = imageInput('/')[-1]
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: you forgot the .split('/') Use the following image_name = imageInput.split('/')[-1]

Answer (score 0):

you can consider `rsplit`

```
imageInput='https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.805972169.4072/fposter,small,wall_texture,product,750x1000.u3.jpg'
opt=imageInput.rsplit('/',1)[0]
```

which give

> https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.805972169.4072